# in IronPython, How do you get what radio button was selected and equate button pressed to a text variable?

Tags: ironpython, revit

I'm relatively new to IronPython.  I can get what radio button was selected, but I'm not sure how to make the variable "logoToUpdate" available to pass on in my script.  Also, is there a more streamlined way to accomplish this type of form?

Here is my code.  The last line is where I'm not getting any text back in the logoToUpdate variable:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("RevitAPIUI")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")

from System.Drawing import Color, Font, FontStyle, Point
from System.Windows.Forms import (Application, BorderStyle, Button, CheckBox,
    Form, Label, Panel, RadioButton)

class CountForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'Radio Button Trial'
        self.Width = 450
        self.Height = 275
        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Text = "Choose a radio button"
        self.label.Location = Point(10, 20)
        self.label.Height = 50
        self.label.Width = 250
        self.CenterToScreen()

        self.radio1 = RadioButton()
        self.radio1.Text = "Default"
        self.radio1.Location = Point(30, 50)
        self.radio1.Width = 75
        self.radio1.Checked = True
        self.Controls.Add(self.radio1)

        self.radio2 = RadioButton()
        self.radio2.Text = "PIN01"
        self.radio2.Location = Point(30, 80)
        self.radio2.Width = 75
        self.radio2.Checked = False
        self.Controls.Add(self.radio2)

        self.radio3 = RadioButton()
        self.radio3.Text = "PIN02"
        self.radio3.Location = Point(110, 80)
        self.radio3.Width = 75
        self.radio3.Checked = False
        self.Controls.Add(self.radio3)

        button = Button()
        button.Text = "Continue"
        button.Location = Point(175, 175)

        button.Click += self.buttonPressed

        self.Controls.Add(self.label)
        self.Controls.Add(button)

    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        if self.radio1.Checked == True:
            logoToUpdate = "(Default) Selected"
        elif self.radio2.Checked == True:
            logoToUpdate = "(PIN01) Selected"
        else:
            logoToUpdate = "(PIN02) Selected"
        self.Close()

form = CountForm()
Application.Run(form)
print "logoToUpdate Selected = " + logoToUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, had to add "form." to the logoToUpdate variable.

```
    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        if self.radio1.Checked == True:
            form.logoToUpdate = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (Default)"
        elif self.radio2.Checked == True:
            form.logoToUpdate = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN01)"
        else:
            form.logoToUpdate = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN10)"
        self.Close()

form = CountForm()
Application.Run(form)
Answer = form.logoToUpdate
print Answer
```